# How to convert data from two different conditions?

Tags: r, matlab

I was looking at similar questions but I couldn't find a case similar to mine.
I have a data frame that for each subject, has multiple observations per condition.

```
DATE        FIRM         beta
2007/1/3    AAPL    -1.484830724
2007/1/4    AAPL    -1.44106242
2007/1/3    ABX     -0.143856121
2007/1/4    ABX     -0.126196004
2007/1/3    AMD     -0.34000246
2007/1/4    AMD     -0.345778331
2007/1/3    AMZN    -1.148531144
2007/1/4    AMZN    -1.051653075
2007/1/3    BAC     -1.775413607
2007/1/4    BAC     -1.514247677
2007/1/3    C       -0.314957499
2007/1/4    C       -0.424694026
2007/1/3    CAT      0.248562922
2007/1/4    CAT      0.061691807
2007/1/3    CHK     -0.991898499
2007/1/4    CHK     -1.221230424
2007/1/3    CMCSA   -1.409432581
2007/1/4    CMCSA   -1.407738422
2007/1/3    CSCO    -0.68245387
2007/1/4    CSCO    -0.509185506
2007/1/3    CVX     -0.950968174
2007/1/4    CVX     -0.73462275
2007/1/3    CY      -0.476404449
```

This is a simple version. I want to convert the data to monthly periods also with different firms. I tried in Matlab, but it bothers because of the strings and number problem. Does anyone have suggestions on how they would do this?

Thanks.

```
DATA = dataset('File','2007.txt');
[Y,M] = datevec(DATA.DATE);
M = num2cell(M);
C = cellfun(@(x,y) [num2str(x) y],DATA.FIRM,M,'un',0);
[y,~,ind]=unique(C);
F=accumarray(ind,DATA.beta,[],@(x)nanmean(x));
ff = [y num2cell(F)];
```

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you posted code for your best attempt, and the error you are getting. Thanks.

Comment: sorry about the format, this code can't filter the year.

Comment: Hi! You can edit your question for adding the code. I've done it for you (although it may not be visible yet, until it is peer-reviewed), but next time you may do it yourself by using the `edit` button. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I am just beginning. Not quite familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what do you mean by converting data to monthly period. But I think the first thing to do is to convert the `Date` column to date class, and then extract `month` information. Here is an example.

```
# Load package
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

# Create example data frame
dat <- data_frame(Date = c("2007/1/3", "2007/1/4", "2007/1/3", 
                  "2007/1/4", "2007/1/3", "2007/1/4"),
                  FIRM = c("AAPL", "AAPL", "ABX", "ABX", "AMD", "AMD"),
                  beta = c(-1.484830724, -1.44106242, -0.143856121,
                           -0.126196004, -0.34000246, -0.345778331)
)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  # Convert the Date column from character to date
  mutate(Date = ymd(Date)) %>%
  # Extract year and month information
  mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date))
```

The function `ymd` can convert the character with the form "yyyy/m/d" or other similar formats to `date` class. After that, the `year` and `month` function can extract year and month information from the date class. Here is the output.

```
dat2
# A tibble: 6 × 5
        Date  FIRM       beta  Year Month
      <date> <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2007-01-03  AAPL -1.4848307  2007     1
2 2007-01-04  AAPL -1.4410624  2007     1
3 2007-01-03   ABX -0.1438561  2007     1
4 2007-01-04   ABX -0.1261960  2007     1
5 2007-01-03   AMD -0.3400025  2007     1
6 2007-01-04   AMD -0.3457783  2007     1
```

Then you may begin other process or analysis of your data.

Comment: Thanks a lot ycw. I forgot to mention the original data are 2007 to 2013 daily data with thirty companies. I'll work on it.

Comment: @Kevin Wang If the format is consistent, the code should still work.